# Is it allowed to drive a bike after 1 (2, 3) beers in Germany?

Tags: legal, germany, alcohol, bicycles

What is the regulation about bicycle driving in Germany? What is the acceptable alcohol rate in blood?

So, am I generally allowed to drive a bicycle after 1 or 2 beers? In Poland, for example, I could go to prison for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dirty-flow's answer is not really wrong, however, I want to substantiate it a little bit. To quote from [fahrrad-recht.de](http://www.fahrrad-recht.de):

> Gut zu wissen: Eine Trunkenheitsfahrt (§ 316 StGB) kann nicht nur mit Kraftfahrzeugen, sondern grundsätzlich auch mit dem Fahrrad begangen werden!
>
> Eine Trunkenheitsfahrt liegt immer dann vor, wenn das Fahrrad nicht mehr sicher geführt werden kann. Eine feste Promillegrenze gibt es hier nicht. Ist der Fahrradfahrer verkehrsauffällig geworden, kann die für Kraftfahrzeuge geltende Grenze von 0,5 Promille ab der eine Ordnungswidrigkeit vorliegt auch für Radfahrer herangezogen werden, hat der sogar einen Unfall verursacht, so ist auch hier - wie bei Kraftfahrzeugen - die 0,3-Promillegrenze ausschlaggebend. Als absolute Fahruntüchtigkeitsgrenze für Radfahrer hat der Bundesgerichtshof 1,7 Promille festgesetzt (bei Kraftfahrzeugen: 1,1 Promille). Einzelne Gerichte haben aber auch schon 1,5 Promille für die absolute Fahruntüchtigkeit ausreichen lassen.
>
> Werden durch die Unfähigkeit, das Rad sicher zu führen, Leib oder Leben eines anderen Menschen oder fremde Sachen von einigem Wert gefährdet, droht gar die Verurteilung wegen Gefährdung des Straßenverkehrs, § 315c StGB.

The translation is more or less (just the important parts):

Driving under the influence of alcohol is generally forbidden, if your not able anymore to participate safely in traffic. There is no concrete alcohol limit for that. If it is clearly obvious that a biker shouldn't participate in traffic, the limit of 0.5 can also be used for bikers. If the biker has caused an accident, it is even possible to use a limit of 0.3. At 1.7 and above, it is illegal in every case. Some courts have also used a 1.5 threshold.

Answer (score 6):

The drink-drive limit for a bicycle in Germany is 1.6. So if you have more, than it's better to walk. But if you drink only a beer or 2, it should be no problem at all

Comment: 1,6 promile? Oh gods, in Poland it's 0,2 :D

Comment: yes, it's still 1,6 promile, but this can change in the future

Comment: It would be surprising if one can walk straight after imbibing such amount of alcohol, let alone partake in activity requiring fine motor coordination and balance.

Comment: It shouldn't really be a problem to walk straight with 1.6, expect maybe if you never drink.

Comment: @lechlukasz I saw a TV report about the extreme treatment of drunk cyclists in Poland. In The Netherlands, and presumably Germany too, the idea is that it's *good* if people go home by bicycle after a night out — then at least they're not driving.

Comment: I didn't know different jurisdictions use different units before. For example, NSW, Australia uses grams of alcohol per 100 millilitres of blood, and the limit is usually 0.02 or 0.05 BAC.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Promille (or per mill in English) is just another way to express the relationship between the amount of alcohol in the blood. 1 Promille is therefore 1.06g / 1 Liter of blood.